# Why does 'Int32 value__' show up as enum member?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm doing some checks on my declared Enums and I'm wondering why `Int32 value__` shows up always as the first enum member in every declared Enum since it is the type of the members and not a member in itself?

Sample code to test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEnumMember()
{
    var type = typeof(Colors);
    var info = type.GetTypeInfo();
    var members = info.DeclaredMembers.ToArray();
    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(member);
    }
}

public enum Colors
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}
```

Output:

```
Debug Trace:
Int32 value__
Colors Red
Colors Blue
Colors Green
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not always. Try to change the definition of the enum to `public enum Colors : byte`. The value member will be `Byte value__` then.

You will see that the first member of an enum is the actual backing storage for the enum value.